# Xcode 11 How to avoid using AutoLayout

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, autolayout

I am designing an application on Xcode using swift 5 and I need the app to be functional on devices from iPhone 6 to 11 pro max and I do not want to use auto layout, as it is too complicated to balance size and functionality. Is there a way to build the UI per device instead of a general one with auto layout

Comment: StackView, Adaptive layout, third party libraries, etc.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini can u expand on that exactly, like a youtube tutorial or something aha

Comment: You are in the wrong way. If you watch a couple of videos about autolayout, you will change your mind about it.